# [Ext.DevTunnelOperationError]: Unable to execute dev tunnel operation 'create'. unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: visual-studio-code, microsoft-teams, imessage-extension, teams-toolkit

So i am using Teams Tookit to create a message extension in Visual Studio Code

When i go on and Click (F5) to Debug Locally -

Sometimes the Toolkit Works and sometimes it gives me this error

**image has been attached below **

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeC4H.png)

I haven't tried anything in particular , but actively looking for solutions to solve this error as soon as possible

Comment: To ensure that you have the most up-to-date version of the Teams Toolkit extension installed in Visual Studio Code, you can check for updates in the Extensions view. Simply search for "Teams Toolkit" and click on the gear icon next to the extension.

Before creating a dev tunnel, make sure that you have the necessary permissions and access. This includes being signed in to your Microsoft 365 account and having the appropriate permissions to create a tunnel.

Comment: IMO, [the suggestion to post this question here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1375702/(ext-devtunneloperationerror)-unable-to-execute-de) by @Nivedipa-MSFT was not the best. I'd have suggested to raise this to https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues. If you do raise an issue ticket there, please ping me here with a link to it. I don't see any issue tickets there with the same error message as you, so I think this is a "new" issue.